# Stock Android on Nexus S - "invalid magic code"

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, rom-flashing, fastboot

I have a Nexus S (2.3.3, GRI54/I9023, bootloader unlocked, clockworkmod recovery installed, rooted) and I'm trying to flash it with a stock system.img that I built myself (no modifications - yet).

To make the stock Android build, I followed the instructions for making a build found at http://source.android.com/source/download.html. The build was successful and the system does work when run on the emulator.

To flash the ROM, I connect the phone, boot with Volume up + Power, connect USB and type

```
fastboot flash system system.img
```

The response that is shown on the phone is

```
Invalid magic code 0x00000003
```

What does this mean? What's wrong?

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/126311/fastboot-erase-system-not-working/213489#213489

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need the stock recovery, based on http://2chnull.info/r/smartphone/1292830738/801-900.  You can get back to stock recovery easily, for example follow this thread: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=884093

Comment: So with an unlocked bootloader and the stock recovery image I should be able to flash ROMs signed with the default test keys that are included in the public Android repository?

Comment: Also, the nandroid backup rom linked in the xda forum is marked GRH78 - could that be a problem for my GRI54? It took me a while to find a custom rom that would work.

Comment: Yes, unlocked bootloader + stock recovery should allow you to flash those ROMs.  I would also assume GRI54 would work just as well as GRH78.